# LOESS/ LOWESS Function with replicates

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, loess

I'm using statsmodels lowess smoother (see documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html)).

Mainly it works fine, but sometimes it produces errors:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/smoothers_lowess.py:165:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
res = _lowess(y, x, frac=frac, it=it, delta=delta)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:4011: RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in median
r = func(a, **kwargs)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/smoothers_lowess.py:165: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
res = _lowess(y, x, frac=frac, it=it, delta=delta)
```

I figured out, that when the input consists of many replicates, these errors are produced.

e.g.:

```
x = [1,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,7]
y = [2,1,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,8,1]

lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(endog = x, exog = y, frac = 0.6666)
```

How can lowess be used in these situations?

Thanks!

Comment: statsmodels lowess cannot handle the case with a large number of ties in x. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2449 The code is too complex to easily fix this.

Comment: Thanks @Josef Do you know an alternative to statsmodels lowess function? I haven't found anything for python. I just want to fit a lowess line to my plot

Comment: No, I don't know of an alternative in Python. I think all nonparametric methods that are designed for the continuous case will have problems in the example.